# SSRS report - access paramters in custom code

Tags: reporting-services

I have to access report paramters in the custom code but in somewhat unusual way.I know I can read a parameter like this:

```
Report.Parameters!dataPart.Value
```

My problem is that because of very long string (> 65k) being sent to the report via the above parameter the report fails. What I am doing in the backend I am adding dynamic parameters something like "dataPart", "dataPart1", "dataPart2", ... I have to combine these parameters together in the report to get a complete data string:

```
Report.Parameters!dataPart.Value + Report.Parameters!dataPart1.Value + Report.Parameters!dataPart2.Value
```

Unless someone nows how to do without hardcoding a few of these parameters at design I dont see any other way.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what you are trying to do any why. Are you trying to parse a large value passed in via a single parameter value, or trying to build the parameter value from other parameters?  Maybe an abridged example would be helpful here. Explain who your parameters are set up (datatypes, multi-value?) and anything else that will explain the current setup. My gut says, use a multi-value parameter and then join() it but it's guessing as I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am running my report using c# HttpClient. Eventhough I am using POST still thre is a limitation on a single SSRS parameter. When I POST I am using content to deliver data to the report because data is prepared in the midde tier. So, a few datasets are injected into the report as json strings. Some datasets are too big so I need to break them into smaller peices and assemble them in the report. The parameters can be param1, pram2, param3, ... but in the report how would I put them together into a single string? The only way to access parameters in the custom code is to use hardcoded names.

Comment: Check this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4688/resolving-the-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception-in-sql-server-reporting-services/